Why my REST Configuration in spring-security.xml not intercepting /rest endpoints?
I am using Spring 6.0 and spring-security 6.1
This is my REST config
    <security:http security-context-explicit-save="true" use-expressions="true" use-authorization-manager="false" pattern="/rest/**" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restServicesEntryPoint">
        <security:custom-filter ref="restServicesFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
    </security:http>
    <bean id="restServicesEntryPoint" class="com.example.webservices.auth.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="Square" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="restServicesFilter" class="com.example.webservices.auth.CustomRestSecurityFilter"/>

This is non-rest Config
<security:http create-session="stateless" security-context-explicit-save="true" use-authorization-manager="false" authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManagerWithMultipleProviders" security-context-repository-ref="nullSecurityContextRepository">
<!-- Login config -->
<security:access-denied-handler error-page="/bs/denied"/>
    <!-- Login config -->   
<security:form-login login-page="/bs/login" authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationSuccessHandler" authentication-failure-handler-ref="customAuthenticationFailureHandler" />
//other codes

When hitting /rest/** endpoints. it is not intercepted by REST security config. Instead of rest config, it is coming through non-rest config.
And if removed property use-authorization-manager=false it is giving circular dependency error.

pattern="/rest/**" is not working. Instead of pattern I created CustomRestMatcher. And it starts intercepting rest endpoints.
security config
`<security:http request-matcher-ref="restMatcher" security-context-explicit-save="true" use-expressions="true" use-authorization-manager="false" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restServicesEntryPoint">
    <security:custom-filter ref="restServicesFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
</security:http>

<bean id="restServicesEntryPoint" class="com.example.webservices.auth.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="Square" />
</bean>
<bean id="restServicesFilter" class="com.example.webservices.auth.CustomRestSecurityFilter"/>
<bean id="restMatcher" class="com.example.CustomRestMatcher" />`

CustomRestMatcher class
public class CustomRestMatcher implements RequestMatcher {
@Override
public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
    // method to check request is rest endpoint or not i.e. starts from /rest/**
    String requestPath = request.getServletPath();
    return requestPath.startsWith("/rest");
}}


In Spring 6.x version , the configuration has changed define bean from  XML-based to Java-based configuration using @Configuration classes and SecurityFilterChain.This approach is more flexible and aligns better with modern Spring practices.
REST Security Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class RestSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain restSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .securityContext().securityContextRepository(new NullSecurityContextRepository()).and()
            .securityContext(context -> context
                .requireExplicitSave(true))
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .requestMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
                .authenticationEntryPoint(restServicesEntryPoint()))
            .addFilterBefore(restServicesFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restServicesEntryPoint() {
        RestAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setRealmName("Square");
        return entryPoint;
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomRestSecurityFilter restServicesFilter() {
        return new CustomRestSecurityFilter();
    }
}

Non REST Security Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class NonRestSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain nonRestSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .securityContext(context -> context
                .requireExplicitSave(true))
            .sessionManagement(session -> session
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/bs/login")
                .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
                .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler()))
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
                .accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler()));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
        AccessDeniedHandlerImpl handler = new AccessDeniedHandlerImpl();
        handler.setErrorPage("/bs/denied");
        return handler;
    }
}


Main COnfiguration

@Configuration
public class MainSecurityConfig {

    @Order(1)
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain restSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return new RestSecurityConfig().restSecurityFilterChain(http);
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain nonRestSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return new NonRestSecurityConfig().nonRestSecurityFilterChain(http);
    }
}


What was wrong with their configuration, other than it being written in XML?

@SotiriosDelimanolis  their configurations not display the filter process order , so potential issue may be that not processed SecurityFilterChain in  right order,  and the env is spring 6 , XML configuration might not support all the latest features and improvements, Java-based configuration  clarify more clearly
